# Colouring a grid 3x3

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Compute the number of ways to color 3 cells in a 3 × 3 grid so that no two colored cells share an edge.

I enumerated it and got an answer of 22? Can somone verify, please.

Thanks

Comment: How did you arrive at that answer? That's more important than the answer itself.

Comment: I thought I said I enumerated it.  Four configurations, Corner cells diagonal 2, 2in row, 1 in adjacent row near coloumn ( 8),  2 in row, 1 in adjacent row farterh column (8) and one more configuration (4) to a total of 22

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include these details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate the cells $1 \cdots 9$ going top to bottom left to right.

Case 1: The middle cell (cell $5$) is colored. Then $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ ways to color the board.

Case 2: The middle cell is not colored. Then the border cells can worked upon.

The border cells are $8$ in count.

Sub-case 1: The cell $1$ is colored. Then $3, 6, 9, 8, 7$ are the cells that can be colored. We can pick $\binom{5}{2} = 10$. Subtract from them the ways to pick adjacent indices $4$. So, add $10 - 4 = 6$

Sub-case 2: The cell $1$ is not colored. Then $2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4$ are the cells that can be colored. Now we have to pick $3$ from this list, so that none is adjacent. Add to answer $\binom{7}{3} = 35$ but this includes the ways in which two or more are adjacent.

Note that there are two ways in which this can happen:

1. All three are adjacent. Subtract $5$
2. Two are adjacent. Other is not. Subtract $20$

How did we get the 20? Consider the adjacent pair is $2, 3$. Now there are $4$ ways for the other element. Consider the adjacent pair is $7, 4$, again $4$ ways. Now for any other pair, there are $3$ ways. So, $4 \cdot 3 + 4 + 4 = 20$

Answer is $10 + 6 + 6 = 22$

Method 2:
Think of the configurationg of the number of cells we are going to paint in each row.

This is either $1 + 1 + 1$ and $2 + 1$, since max $2$ colored cells in a row.

For, first configuration, there are $3 \cdot 2 ^ 2$ ways. (Color first cell in any way, then 2 option for the rest of the rows, as the column with the color in the upper row can't be painted). This equals 12.

Now, let's iterate on the row with $2$ colored cells. Only $1$ way for a row to have $2$ colors.

First Row -> $4$ options for the other cell
Second Row -> $2$ options for the other cell
Third Row -> $4$ options for the other cell

Total = $12$ + $10$ = $22$

Comment: If the middle cell is colored, you must choose $2$ of $4$ corner cells. There are $6$ ways to do this.

Comment: @paw88789 Oops I ddin't read the 3 - cell condition. I thought that any number of cells can be picked. I have edited the post now. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Alternatively in case 2 there are $\binom83=56$ ways to coose $3$ non-central cells, $8$ ways to choose three consecutive cells, $8\cdot4=32$ ways to choose two consecutive and one nonconsecutive, so $56-8-32=16$ good triples without using the central cell.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that uses the inclusion-exclusion principle.  From among all $3$-subsets of the $3^2$ cells, you want to count the ones that avoid the $12$ properties (one per edge) that both cells corresponding to the edge are selected.  If you ignore all $12$ properties, there are $\binom{9}{3}$ choices.  If you consider one of the $12$ properties, there are $\binom{7}{1}$ choices for the other cell among the other $9-2$ cells.  If you consider two of the $12$ properties, they must overlap in exactly one cell (which is a corner cell, an edge cell, or the center cell).  You cannot have more than two of the $12$ properties.

Putting this all together, inclusion-exclusion yields:
$$\binom{12}{0}\binom{9}{3} - \binom{12}{1}\binom{7}{1} + \left(4\binom{2}{2}+4\binom{3}{2}+1\binom{4}{2}\right) = 84 - 84 + 22 = 22$$

Comment: Could you explain the solution further. It is terse and I cant understand what properties you are referring to

Comment: I added some details just now.